# ClassCastException when inserting into a TreeSet

Tags: java, exception, gwt, casting

Having the following Java TreeSet

```
TreeSet<Widget> tabs = new TreeSet<Widget>();
```

When I do `tabs.add(new Widget());`in method a() it worked. When I do the same in method b() shortly after the first insert is performed I the a ClassCastException.

Change

```
ArrayList<Widget> tabs = new ArrayList<Widget>();
```

It works fine in both methods a() and b() without any error. I was wondering why there is a ClassCastException in the first example. There is no casting in place.

Edit: Here are method a, b and the Widget class:

```
 private void a() {
   tabs.add(new Widget());
 }

 private void b() {
   tabs.add(new Widget());
 }

public class Widget() {}
```

**How do I make the first example to work?**

Comment: They both are valid usage. What's the exact stacktrace and if you modified the code, then please paste the code as is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add to a `TreeSet`, the object you pass must either implement `Comparable` **or** you must specify a `Comparator` at the time the `TreeSet` is constructed.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a `Comparator` provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

And the [JavaDoc for `TreeSet.add(E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E)) even tells you why this happens...

> **ClassCastException** - *if the specified object cannot be compared with the elements currently in this set*